# How to send the correct order of information to webservice?

Tags: android, asynchronous, request, retrofit

I have some videos files in a Android directory and I want execute each one using `Intent`. So far no problem, however I need save which video is running (log) in my webservice, so that, I make a asynchronous request, using retrofit 1.9.0, after `startActivity(intent)`. My problem is: the log is not save in the right order. All logs are save with the same hour.

This is my function:

```
    File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    for (int i = 0; i < videoListFromDevice.size(); i++) {

        if (isFileInDirectory(videoListFromDevice.get(i).name)) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Videos/" + videoListFromDevice.get(i).name + ".mp4");
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/mp4");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);

            getPresenter().sendLogVideo(MainPresenter.DEFAULT_NAME, videoListFromDevice.get(i).name);

        }
    }
```

Where `videoListFromDevice` is a local list of videos.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logs are executed in a task sequence execution, You should use the `Log.v(), Log.d(), Log.i(), Log.w(), and Log.e()` methods to **Write/Trace logs**. You can then view the logs in **logcat**.

For ex,
Declare a TAG constant in your class:

```
private static final String TAG = "VideoActivity";
```

and use that in subsequent calls to the log methods.

Something like this: `Log.d(TAG, "videoName=" + video);`

For more info see [Log | Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

**EDIT:**

You can fetch `logcat` data as follows:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
String data;
while ((data= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     log.append(data);
   }
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewlog);
textView.setText(log.toString());
```

Don't forgot to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

To get data for particular TAG:
replace `logcat -d` with `logcat -d -s YourTag`

Comment: O know this, but I need save this log in my webservice. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @JoséAurimarSepkaJr check the updated ans. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry @H.P. but I don't understand your code above.

Comment: @JoséAurimarSepkaJr what you don't understand in the code? It's simple code reading data from logcat until end of log file, append it to string builder and then set logs in text view.

Comment: Actually, I think my problem is in the asynchronous request and not in get a log.